# Can't get Django format localization working

Tags: django, localization

I am trying out [Django 1.2's spiffy new localization feature](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#format-localization).

```
settings.py

    USE_L10N = True
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'sv-SE'

sometemplate.html

    {{32.519823}}
```

Is rendered as: 32.519823

In Sweden, the decimal separator should be (, comma) not (. period). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, it's because `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` is defined as `'.'` in `formats.py` for the sv locale (incorrectly, IMHO).

To solve this I overrided `FORMAT_MODULE_PATH` using [this reference.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#format-module-path) Thanks to *Brandon* in #django for helping me.